# Win8 - WCF/Entity Framework with SQL Server DB Does Not Work when Deployed to IIS

Tags: sql-server, wcf, entity-framework

I have a similar problem to [WCF/Entity Framework with External SQL Server DB Does Not Work when Deployed to IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448160/wcf-entity-framework-with-external-sql-server-db-does-not-work-when-deployed-to) except that this is on Windows 8 and the database server is not remote. It is on the same machine and there is NO DOMAIN. The first part of the script works but there is no user IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET 4.0 account. There is app pools like .NET 4.5 on Windows 8 and it seems to like that but this still doesn't work. I know it is some kind of permissions issue. Can anyone help with a script or answer so this will work? I have to be able to create WCF services with EF. Thanks.

I tried a modified script from the first topic:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [sgentile-hp\sgentile] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
GO
USE [AdventureWorks2012]
GO
CREATE USER [sgentile-hp\sgentile] FOR LOGIN [sgentile-hp\sgentile]
GO
USE [AdventureWorks2012]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'sgentile-hp\sgentile'
GO
USE [AdventureWorks2012]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'sgentile-hp\sgentile'
GO
```

That produced:

```
Msg 15025, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
The server principal 'sgentile-hp\sgentile' already exists.
Msg 15063, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The login already has an account under a different user name.
Msg 15410, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_addrolemember, Line 35
User or role 'sgentile-hp\sgentile' does not exist in this database.
Msg 15410, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_addrolemember, Line 35
User or role 'sgentile-hp\sgentile' does not exist in this database.
```

I also tried creating a SQL authenticated user and using its name and password in the connection string but still doesn't work. There has to be a way of running the App Pool with the user.

Comment: >You either have to run your app pool under a domain account and give that user rights in your database or, with mixed mode authentication turned on on the sql server, create an SQL authenticated user and put it's name and password in your connection string.

I created SQL authenticated user and put it's user name and password in connection string and still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding a SQL Authenticated User and putting that name and password in the web.config. The Error Log was showing me "Login failed for user 'Indigo'.  Reason: The password of the account must be changed." As soon as I changed it, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I would proceed with small steps.
First of all, you should find the **login** [sgentile-hp\sgentile] under the server logins (just to be clear, in Management Studio go under Security/Logins and you should find your user here).
If you find it, the "create login" statement worked well.
Then go under your AdventureWorks2012 database in Management Studio Object Explorer, and go under Security/Users, where you should find the **database user** [sgentile-hp\sgentile]; delete it and run the statement:

```
USE [AdventureWorks2012]
GO
CREATE USER [sgentile-hp\sgentile] FOR LOGIN [sgentile-hp\sgentile]
GO
```

again. This should correctly map the server login with the corresponding user in the database. You can then assign to this user the db_datareader and db_datawriter database roles.
On the IIS side, make the **windows user** [sgentile-hp\sgentile] member of IIS_IUSRS local group, and then configure your IIS app pool in order to start on the context of this user; specify

```
Integrated Security=SSPI
```

in your service's connection string: now the WCF service that runs under this app pool, should be able to correctly connect to your database.

Hope This Helps